# Opengl ES 2.0 : Get texture size and other info

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The context of the question is OpenGL ES 2.0 in the Android environment. I have a texture. No problem to display or use it.

Is there a method to know its width and height and other info (like internal format) simply starting from its binding id?

I need to save texture to bitmap without knowing the texture size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not in ES 2.0. It's actually kind of surprising that the functionality is not there. You can get the size of a renderbuffer, but not the size of a texture, which seems inconsistent.

The only thing available are the values you can get with `glGetTexParameteriv()`, which are the `FILTER` and `WRAP` parameters for the texture.

It's still not in ES 3.0 either. Only in ES 3.1, `glGetTexLevelParameteriv()` was added, which gives you access to all the values you're looking for. For example to get the width and height of the currently bound texture:

```
int[] texDims = new int[2];
GLES31.glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, texDims, 0);
GLES31.glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, texDims, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Reto Koradi said there is no way to do it but you can store the width and height of a texture when you are loading it from android context before you bind it in OpenGL.

```
    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = am.open(name);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    // here is you bind your texture in openGL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a hack for doing this. Use ESSL's textureSize function. To access its result from the CPU side you're going to have to pass the texture as an uniform to a shader, and output the texture size as the r & g components of your shader output. Apply this shader to an 1x1px primitive drawn to a 1x1px FBO, then readback the drawn value from the GPU with `glReadPixels`.

You'll have to be careful with rounding, clamping and FBO formats. You may need a 16-bit integer FBO format.