# OpenGL: does a texture have storage?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL, after a texture name is generated, the texture does not have storage. With glTexImage2D you can create storage for the texture.

How can you determine if a texture has storage?

Comment: Is the kneejerk "submit a texture with a `NULL` `data` parameter and you'll have the determined behaviour that all textures always have storage" helpful? If your problem is that you definitely want safely to be able to `glTexSubImage` then it is, otherwise I think I'm one of those awkward people that won't just answer the question set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [glGetTexLevelParameterfv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872044(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the height (or width) of the texture. A value of zero for either of these parameters means the texture name represents the null texture.

*Note I haven't tested this!*

Comment: Unfortunately this is not available in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: That is strange, I also saw this question that confirms this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140178/opengl-es-2-0-get-texture-size-and-other-info . Weird, maybe you can track of which texture names have store yourself?

Comment: In ES, this is only available in 3.1 and later.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do exactly that in ES 2.0. In ES 3.1 and later, you can call:

```
GLint width = 0;
glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width);
if (width > 0) {
    // texture has storage
}
```

The `glIsTexture()` call that is available in ES 2.0 may give you the desired information depending on what exactly your requirements are. While it will not tell you if the texture has storage, it will tell you if the given id is valid, and if it was ever bound as a texture. For example:

```
GLuint texId = 0;
GLboolean isTex = glIsTexture(texId);
// Result is GL_FALSE because texId is not a valid texture name.

glGenTextures(1, &texId);
isTex = glIsTexture(texId);
// Result is GL_FALSE because, while texId is a valid name, it was never
// bound yet, so the texture object has not been created.

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
isTex = glIsTexture(texId);
// Result is GL_TRUE because the texture object was created when the
// texture was previously bound.
```