# Is it possible to get SurfaceTexture dimensions?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am working with [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture) and I need to figure out the image dimensions just from the [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture) object, I was thinking about using the *OpenGL* but this functionality is available only by using *OpenGL ES 3.1*, as [this answer implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140178/opengl-es-2-0-get-texture-size-and-other-info). Any ideas?

I can't really store the texture dimensions ahead of time since what I do is that I initialize Surface with the SurfaceTexture and then some injected module draws on to the Surface. Sadly, I cannot rely for the module to provide me with the dimensions.

EDIT: So far i did this suboptimal solution to work with the texture - I know the subregion of texture that's being drawn on screen and I can allocate `(windowWidth / widthRatio, windowHeight / heightRatio)` buffer to work with the texture without any distortions.